# 404 error when trying POST to php file in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js

I have seen a lot of questions here with the exact same problem, but none of them have a solution that works for me.

I have a NodeJS server setup and in an Angular controller I'm trying to get a contact form working. On form submission I call this function (this is only one of the many variations on a POST request I've tried):

```
$scope.submit_contact_form = function(){
    $http({
        method: "post",
        url: 'http://' +  window.location.host + "/form-u10657.php",
        data: $scope.form_data,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.status_message_toggle("Success");
    }).error(function(){
        $scope.status_message_toggle("Problem sending mail", 'warning');
    });
};
```

But it always returns a 404 not found error. The php file is definitely in the right directory. Going to the url with a GET request works.

What is different in my setup, that I haven't seen in other questions, is that I am using a NodeJS server and ngRouteProvider.
Other answers have said to allow NodeJS to accept POST requests, but it hasn't been necessary to configure NodeJS before, and I would like to avoid it now.

Is there a way to fix it just in Angular? And if not what should I do with NodeJS to get it working?